# Why can't you append a pointer to an array?

Tags: pointers, go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Circle struct {
  x string
}

func main() {
    circle := Circle{x: "blah"}
    results := make([]*Circle, 1)
    results = append(results, &circle)
    fmt.Printf("Here: %s\n", results[0].x)
}
```

If I change the line `results = append(results, &circle)` to `results[0] = &circle` works fine. Couldn't find any reason as to why that would be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can, it's just that you *are* appending to the slice, which means that the element you add is in `results[1]`, and `results[0]` is a `nil` pointer (the default value for a pointer).

You could do `results := make([]*Circle, 0, 1)` to give it a capacity of 1 but a length of zero, or you could do `results := []*Circle{}` (most compact), or you could simply keep the version where you assign to `results[0]`, since it works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can, but you are using `make` with length 1, so the [0] index is already set (to a nil Circle...)

Changing your `results[0].x` to `results[1].x` works, but without using `make` works as expected:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Circle struct {
  x string
}

func main() {
    circle := Circle{x: "blah"}
    results := []*Circle{} // initialize empty slice of Circle pointers
    results = append(results, &circle)
    fmt.Printf("Here: %s\n", results[0].x)
}
```

Run in playground: https://play.golang.org/p/7vMOfAXvgI

Comment: Thank you! My array syntax was incorrect. I had a pointer to an array when I wanted an array of pointers.